# Thread.sleep() is too fast in some android devices

Tags: android, multithreading

I do not know why but i created a thread where i am using Thread.sleep(1000) and its working in 8 out of 10 devices but not working in rest 2 devices.

Not working means, thread is sleeping for around 0.5 sec instead of 1 sec and i can see it in logs.

So there is no guarantee that thread will sleep for exact amount of time ?

What could be the possible issues ?

Same code is working in almost devices.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that `Thread.sleep` will sleep for an exact amount of time.  What the javadoc actually says is:

> *"Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, **subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers**."*

Sleeping longer than expected it not unexpected.  For example, it can happen if the device's cores are all busy doing other things when the "sleep" is due to end.

However, a `sleep()` call returning significantly sooner than requested sleep time **is not** expected behavior.

I suspect that the real cause is:

- Your thread is getting an interrupt and your code is squashing the exception ... so you don't notice it.  An interrupt send to a sleeping thread will cause the `sleep` call to return early.
- Your `sleep` call's argument is different to what you think.
- Possibly a system clock adjustment happened at the wrong time ... though I would expect this to be a "once in a blue moon" event.
- This is an artifact of an emulator, a debugger or something like that "messing" with the clock.

However, if this is a real effect and not caused by something that you are doing, then I would say that it is a candidate for reporting as a bug to the vendor of the device.  But you would need a way to demonstrate the problem repeatably; i.e. a minimal reproducible example to include in your bug report.

Comment: Ok will update issue , after carefully reading my code with the possible causes given by you. Then i will make a minimal code which reproduces the issue or bug (if it is)

Answer (score 0):

The sleep() documentation warns that it's not precise:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#sleep%28long%29

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
> execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the
> precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread
> does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Indeed, you haven't even quoted the linked javadoc correctly.  What the javadoc actually states (Java SE and Android) is *"Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers."*.  It does not say "more or less than requested".

Comment: Sleeping longer that the requested time is to be expected.  But sleeping significantly less time is not expected.  If there was irrefutable evidence that this is really happening (consistently), I would be inclined to call it a bug.  (But we'd need to see the evidence, including the source code of the program that produced it.)